# Chai-As-Promised: Handle errors when promise throws error

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, bluebird, chai

I have the following code I need to test:

```
function A(param){
  // Process param
  return B(param)
     .catch(function(err){
      //Process err
      throw new customError(err); // throw a custom Error
     })
     .then(function(response){
       // Handle response and return
       return {status: 'Success'}
     })
}
```

To test it, I use the following snippet:

```
return expect(A(param))
             .to.eventually.have.property('status', 'Success');
```

This works fine when the code doesn't break in function A or B, but when it does, the test case fails, and the `grunt-mocha` fails to exit, which I presume is due to the fact that it still waiting for A to resolve.

If I add a `return` statement instead of `throw` in catch block, grunt-mocha exits fine. Is there a better way to test such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch is meant to catch and correct any errors, not re-throw them. So returning the error or a rejected promise is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: `Promise.reject` sounds the right thing to do. Thanks